# wget fails but opening in browser succeeds. How?

Tags: browser, pdf, download, wget

I was trying to download a pdf from the intel website at [this address](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf). When I open it through the browser(`google-chrome`) there seems to be no problem in viewing it or storing it on the my hard disk. 
 But when I tried to 
`wget http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf`, 
I got the following error:

```
Connecting to www.intel.com|128.230.11.57|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2012-03-12 16:12:25 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

FYI, There was no login required on the website. Why would this happen?

Comment: User-agent filtering?

Comment: Maybe the server handles command-line user agents differently than "normal" browsers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case the site is checking User-Agent.  `wget --user-agent=Safari ...` downloads the file without problem.  (Everyone fears blocking Apple's customers, apparently.)

Comment: I try to download this file failed:wget --user-agent=Safari https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/raw-attachment/ticket/5069/rein_cmakelists2.patch

Comment: How to solve that problem? Thank you~

Comment: You should ask a new question